# set values to fields in adminhtml form template

Tags: magento-1.8, adminform

I'd created a template file for admin form tab as:

```
class Excellence_Designer_Block_Adminhtml_Designer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {

    protected function _beforeToHtml() {
        $this->addTab('images', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('designer')->__('Images'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('designer')->__('Images'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('designer/adminhtml_designer_edit_tab_images')->toHtml(),
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

}
```

---

```
class Excellence_Designer_Block_Adminhtml_Designer_Edit_Tab_Images extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template implements
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {

    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('designer/edit/tab/images.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Images');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Images');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

**images.phtml**

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="image">Custom Field</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="image" id="image" />
</div>
```

but there's no value in there if I do want to edit the form

[image: screen shot] even the value is saved in database. The other tab was created with `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` and showing the values in fields but for this how could I get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd come to a solution don't know is it the right approach but works in my case. If you have a better solution then let me know.

I'd made a change in **images.phtml**

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="image">Custom Field</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getValue(); ?>" class="input-text" name="image" id="image" />
</div>
```

and added a method in the respective block file

```
public function getValue() {
    return Mage::registry('designer_data')->getImage();
}
```