# upload multiple files with Varien_File_Uploader

Tags: magento-1.8, multiple-file-upload, varien-file-uploader

This question is related to my previous [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/17257/4426) where I'd created a tab form in admin using a template file. The content of template file is:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">Images</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="hor-scroll">
            <table class="form-list container">
                <tr class="wrapper-tr">
                    <td class="value">
                        <input type="file" name="images[]"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label">
                        <span class="remove">Remove</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Image"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.add').click(function() {
            var wrapper = "<tr class='wrapper-tr'>" +
                    "<td class='value'><input type='file' name='images[]'></td>" +
                    "<td class='label'><span class='remove'>Remove</span></td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            jQuery(wrapper).find('.remove').on('click', function() {
                jQuery(this).parent('.wrapper-tr').remove();
            });
            jQuery(wrapper).appendTo('.container');
        });
        jQuery('.container').on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
            if (jQuery('.wrapper-tr').length > 1) {
                jQuery(this).parents('.wrapper-tr').remove();
            } else {
                alert('at least one image need to be selected');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

for uploading multiple files.

But as my *input* type name is `images[]` that's why in my controller's `saveAction()` I'm unable to upload file using `Varien_File_Uploader` as:

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('images');
```

what value should I pass in `Varien_File_Uploader` constructor in order to be able to upload file?

**Update**
I tried logging and found this warning:

> Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given  in /var/www/mageqb/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php on line 150

Code in my controller is:

```
foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $image) {
    Mage::log('looping');
    if (empty($image)) {
        Mage::log('continue');
        continue;
    }
    try {
        Mage::log('uploading');
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('images');

        // Any extention would work
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'authors' . DS;
        $img = $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        Mage::log($img['file']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this is the expected code

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
        array(
    'name' => $_FILES['images']['name'][$key],
    'type' => $_FILES['images']['type'][$key],
    'tmp_name' => $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key],
    'error' => $_FILES['images']['error'][$key],
    'size' => $_FILES['images']['size'][$key]
        )
);
```

Comment: What is the $key in this?

Comment: I tried above code but only one file is uploaded.can you please help

Comment: @J.Jenith: perhaps, you have got only one item in `$_FILES`. can you verify the size of array received at your end?

Comment: Thanks , yes i got one item but i upload multiple files
`jQuery('#front_files input[type="file"]').each(function(index){
      var file_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                  file_data = jQuery(this)[0].files; // get multiple files from input file
              
                 if(file_data.length >0 ){
                  
                   formdata.append('upload_artworks', file_data[0]); // we can put more than 1 image file
     }
              
           }); `

Comment: Add below is my Ajax code
`jQuery.ajax({
  console.log(files);
url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('customuploadfile/index/index') ?>",
type: "POST",
data:{collection : files},
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function (result) {
     }
});`

Comment: @J.Jenith: so this is clearly a JavaScript issue where in your `data:{collection: files}` you have just one item. Its better you should ask a new question for the same.

Comment: thanks, i change  `data:{collection:files}` to `data:formdata`
Now its working..

Comment: @J.Jenith: Good to know. :)